# Extracting days from a string Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract the days using regex groups in C# from the following string,

```
"RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;UNTIL=20211126T143000Z;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=-1"
```

I am new to regular expressions and looked at various websites to try write an expression the expression i have got so far is the following

```
(?:BYDAY=)([A-Z,]*);
```

Which matches

```
MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;
```

as a whole, which i can then use ',' in a split to achieve what I want, I wanted to know if there is a way of doing this purely in Regex.

Comment: It depends on the regex flavour. You could get capturing groups `(?:\G(?!^)|BYDAY=)([A-Z]+),?` https://regex101.com/r/bz7hFo/1 or matches `(?<=BYDAY=[A-Z,]*)[A-Z]+` https://regex101.com/r/2oYatq/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Post https://ideone.com/TgwO6r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a quantifier in the lookbehind is supported, you might use:

```
(?<=BYDAY=[A-Z,]*)[A-Z]+
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `BYDAY=[A-Z,]*` match `BYDAY=` followed by 0 or more times A-Z or ,
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ chars A-Z

[.Net regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3dBYDAY%3d%5bA-Z%2c%5d*%29%5bA-Z%5d%2b&i=RRULE%3aFREQ%3dMONTHLY%3bUNTIL%3d20211126T143000Z%3bINTERVAL%3d1%3bBYDAY%3dMO%2cTU%2cWE%2cTH%2cFR%3bBYSETPOS%3d-1) | [C# demo by WiktorStribiżew](https://ideone.com/TgwO6r)

Alternatively you can make use of the `\G` anchor to get iterative matches and capture the value in group 1

```
(?:\G(?!^)|BYDAY=)([A-Z]+),?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bz7hFo/1)